# Kettle PDI: better lookup and insert update or insert update + lookup

Tags: kettle, pdi

In Kettle, aka Pentaho Data Integration, I read an xls with some products linked to some categories and I insert them in a db.

The relationship category-product is 1:n (one category has more products, one product is of one category).
I do the insert of category, then the insert of the product.

CASE 1:

1. Insert/update category (really, i do insert only);
2. Lookup category by code and return the id used in the other steps;

CASE 2:

1. Lookup category by code;
2. Filter row: if(id>0) then go to other steps; else go to step 3;
3. insert category and return id;

Is better (faster/memory use) the case 1 or the case 2?

The same choose is applied to sub-category, supplyer and other related entities.

Actually I use case 1 and pdi process 4 record per second and I have files with 100k records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use the 2nd method, reading the products and for each product use the `Lookup steam` to find the one category of the product.

The reason to go that way is that it is the way a human thinks. And also that the. `Lookup stream` (not the `Lookup Database`) is pretty optimized. In some case even quicker than a database left join.